# Iterate through Complex Object in a repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

My repeater is bound off an object called BillType, inside BillType object, there is a list of another object called Vendors. When I bind to my repeater, I would like my nested repeater to print out the Vendors. But I have no idea how to iterate through the list or perhaps access the Vendor list inside the BillType. Can someone shed a little light. Thanks

```
//this is inside my .aspx nested Repeater
<%#                                                      
((HouseBudget.Business.BillType)Container.DataItem).VendorList.Count > 0 ?                           ((HouseBudget.Business.BillType)Container.DataItem).VendorList[0].VendorName : null %>

I can see there is Vendor information in there when I debug.
((HouseBudget.Business.BillType)Container.DataItem).VendorList
Count = 3
    [0]: {HouseBudget.Business.Vendor}
    [1]: {HouseBudget.Business.Vendor}
    [2]: {HouseBudget.Business.Vendor}

//This is how I can access one record, but I would like to write out all records
((HouseBudget.Business.BillType)Container.DataItem).VendorList[0].VendorName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use nested repeater. Important part here is to bind data source of nested repeater to property of data item of outer repeater (`DataSource='<%# VendorList %>'`)

```
<asp:Repeater ID='rptBillTypes' runat='server' DataSourceID='...'>
   <ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Literal ID='litClient' runat='server' Text='<%# Client %>' />

     <asp:Repeater ID='rptVendors' runat='server' DataSource='<%# VendorList %>'>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Literal ID='litVendorName' runat='server' Text='<%# VendorName %>' />           
        </ItemTemplate>
        <SeparatorTemplate>, </SeparatorTemplate>
     </asp:Repeater>

   </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: I am going to give this a try

Comment: Thanks so much, I set my dataSource to ((HouseBudget.Business.BillType)Container.DataItem).VendorList and then everything worked so good. Thanks